# DI with user-defined InjectionToken not working with AOT enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, typescript2.0, angular2-aot

I have the following constructor:

```
constructor(env: Env, private logger: Logger,
  @Inject(MockEndpoints.TOKEN) @Optional() 
  private endpoints: MockEndpoints[]) {
    // ...
}
```

which works as expected with JIT compiler.
But with AOT compiler enabled it produces build error:
`ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for MockBackendInterceptor in /path/mock-backend.interceptor.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).`

The token object is defined as below:

```
export interface MockEndpoints {
  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any>;
}

export namespace MockEndpoints {
  export const TOKEN: InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]> = 
    new InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]>('MockEndpoints');
}
```

I was convinced that this exactly as recommended by the docs.
Any hint? ;)

EDIT (as response to Gunter's comment):
The endpoints are registered in the same module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MockBackendInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: MockEndpoints.TOKEN, useClass: MockBackupService, multi: true },
    { provide: MockEndpoints.TOKEN, useClass: MockConfigurationService, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class MockBackendModule { }
```

Comment: Where and how do you provide the endpoints?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the question

Comment: The `MockBackendModule` is imported to the module that contains the constructor where it's failing?

Comment: No, I updated once again ;) it is the same module

Comment: And it's working when you remove `@Optional()`? Have you tried `private endpoints?: MockEndpoints[]`?

Comment: Actually not ;) I tested just now. So it works with JIT and does not work with AOT no matter if @Optional is there or not.

Comment: Try creating token without namespace.

Comment: @yurzui - I tried it before asking - does not matter.

Comment: Angular can't understand this part `MockEndpoints.TOKEN`. Is it your first aot build with `@Inject`? Have you used it before? I just wonder whether it is configuration problem or angular can't collect metadata correctly

Comment: I replaced the token with strings `{ provide: 'MockEndpoints' ...` and  `@Inject('MockEndpoints') @Optional() ...` and it actually builds correctly. So my question is - Shouldn't I use InjectionToken for AOT?

Comment: It should work with InjectionToken. `export const EndpointsToken = new InjectionToken(..)` and then `@Inject(EndpointsToken)`

Comment: But it does not work then. I may be wrong but I noticed this behaviour after upgrading to from angular 4 to 5. Or may be the reason is that  `InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]>('MockEndpoints')` MockEndpoints is an interface (not class)?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in small github repo? Which versions angular and @angular/cli are you using?

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 8.4.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0

Comment: Ok i'll try t reproduce it in separate small repo

Comment: Also changing MockEndpoints from interface to abstract class fixes the problem.

Comment: It means that you didn't try what i wrote `export const EndpointsToken = new InjectionToken(..` I asked you to try another simple InjectionToken

Comment: I tried `export const EndpointsToken = new InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]>('MockEndpoints')` - wasn't this what you meant? As long as MockEndpoints was intrerface it produced compilation error. When I changed it to abstract class it started to compile.

Comment: And then `@Inject(EndpointsToken)`?

Comment: As I wrote above. It did NOT work when MockEndpoints was an interface. when I changed it to an abstract class it started working.

Comment: Where do you see i use interface? `@Inject(EndpointsToken)`

Comment: in `new InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]>('string')`  => `MockEndpoints` was an interface. when i made it abstract class it started to compile.

Comment: I see but it I didn't write `MockEndpoints` anywhere)

Comment: So it's de facto `InjectionToken<{}>` or `InjectionToken<any>` - anyway the problem was using interface in parametrizing `InjectionToken` instance

Comment: I tested it: `export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken('MockEndpoints');` with `@Inject(TOKEN) @Optional() private endpoints: MockEndpoint[]` does not work too.

Comment: Just tried it and it works. But i used angular@5.2.1 angular/cli@1.6.5

Comment: Please notice that it is "multi" provider and so the injected type is an array. Still works ? ;)

Comment: Yeah, i use multi `{ provide: TOKEN, useClass: MockConfigurationService, multi: true }` together with `constructor(@Inject(TOKEN) @Optional() private endpoints: MockEndpoint[])` where token is `export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken('MockEndpoints');`

Comment: I upgraded to angular@5.2.1 angular/cli@1.6.5 and it it still behaves the same way (error with interface, compiles with abstract class). Are you sure you use AOT when building? `ng build --aot=true`

Comment: Yes, i built it with aot. `ng build --prod` See also https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md#--dev-vs---prod-builds aot enable when using `prod` flag

Comment: @yurzui And which class in your code has the constructor `constructor(@Inject(TOKEN) @Optional()  private endpoints: MockEndpoint[]...`, where it is registered?

Comment: I tested with AppComponent

Comment: @yurzui - I tested once again with interface but extracting token constant of the namespace and it worked this time. So your suggestion was correct. I guess I must have not saved file when testing for the first time ;).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the reason.

Great thanks to users `yurzui` and `Günter Zöchbauer` for their comments which helped with spotting the problem.

**SOLUTION**

**If (and only if)** the token constant is declared inside a namespace,
the parametrizing type of the `InjectionToken` (e.g. `MockEndpoints` in this case) can not be an interface. So it sufficed then to change it to be an abstract class instead.

```
export abstract class MockEndpoints {
  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any>;
}

export namespace MockEndpoints {
  export const TOKEN: InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]> = 
    new InjectionToken<MockEndpoints[]>('MockEndpoints');
}
```

It was even simpler to just extract the TOKEN constant out of the namespace.

```
export interface MockEndpoint {
  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any>;
}

export const MOCK_ENDPOINT = new InjectionToken<MockEndpoint[]>('MockEndpoints');
```

Notice that the fact that the namespace name was the identical as the interface name (in this case both names `MockEndpoints`) had no meaning. When token constant was declared inside namespace different name it didn't work with interface as parametrizing type.

Of course it also worked with plain string token instead of using `InjectionToken` interface.

This behavour occured only when compiling with AOT. With JIT there were no problems in either case.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you so much!